# Django enable anonymous user session

Tags: django

Hi I want to enable session for anonymous user in Django. When i Log in i can see a session id in cookie. But when i log out there is no session id. I want to use the cookie to store some cart data.

I want to create a session object in which i want to store the data of products an anonymous user adds to the cart. Also i want the same session object to persist when a user logs in after adding items to cart. so that he can checkout.

I can add or retrieve data from a session object but i couldn't figure out how to create a session object for an anonymous user.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    # create your session data for anonymous user
```

but I would not save cart data into session. I would save them into database

Answer (score 0):

just you can use the following code inside your view:

```
if not request.session or not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
```

if the user is anonymous(not logged in user) the session id will created, and you can add your cart items (or anything you want ) in this session , and after the user will logged-in to your system, the session id will remines the same .

i hope this helpful .